# Windows 10 and XP on the same computer on two hard discs - disk check for errors after switch

Tags: windows-xp, boot, windows-10, multi-boot

I have two hard disks:

1. one with Windows XP 32-bit installed on MBR partition
2. second one with new Windows 10 64-bit on GPT partition, run normally as SATA

Both Windows systems work very well. They have to be booted with a little different settings in BIOS (IDE <--> AHCI and Other OS <--> Windows UEFI) and as first drive in the boot sequence.

However (only) during switch between them at least one changes something on the disk with XP, what triggers disk check for errors, or even Norton Security virus check. But never any error has been found. In case of switch

- Windows 10 > Windows XP > Windows 10
  Windows 10 as first one wants to check drives for errors (and later XP), after switch
- Windows XP > Windows 10 > Windows XP
  Windows XP wants to check disk (and later 10).

In case of work on one system (including turning off and on computer, rebooting) such behavior doesn't occur. Only after switch from one OS to another. This disk error check can be skipped, but it is disturbing.

The question is what's that and how to stop this.

Windows XP is known to delete restore points in newer systems, because their system changed somehow, but in this case looks like something is changing on XP disk, since Windows XP can't read at all GPT disk.

Comment: Win10 may still be writing NTFS metadata that XP's very outdated NTFS driver does not understand. That would look to XP as though the file system may have gotten corrupted, triggering a chkdsk scan. This is especially likely to happen if you have restore points enabled for the XP partition, or if you are doing any other kinds of writes the XP partition. Symbolic links, in particular, will be unrecognized by XP. *(Seriously, people, stop using 14-year-old operating systems!!)*

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of Windows 10 fast boot. Disable it (Control Panel / Power Options / Choose what the power buttons do / Change settings that are currently unavailable / Shutdown settings / Turn on fast startup = OFF) and chkdsk won't run each time you boot Windows XP.

Reason why Windows XP chkdsk runs is a new format of NTFS metadata log in Windows 10 system partition. NTFS metadata log will be empty if fast boot is disabled.

Comment: I will change these settings and try this tomorrow morning - boot from XP and later from 10. And day after tomorrow to check what is going with XP. I don't want do it right now, because frequent rebooting is not good for disks.

Comment: With fast startup = OFF: Next day (on Friday) in the morning after  [> Windows XP > Windows 10] Windows XP displayed disk check for errors request at start, but very incomplete, very fast. And normally this should happen after [> Windows XP > Windows 10 > Windows XP], so that was something new. I forgot what did Windows 10 ... But on Saturday (today) after  [> Windows XP > Windows 10] and second  [> Windows XP > Windows 10] no one system displayed such requests neither in the first or second case.

Comment: But I think that fast startup should be disabled only in case of frequent switches between systems, because it is useful and maybe this is better for the hard disk ?

Comment: Fast startup loads the hibernation file (Hiberfil.sys) what probably means more hard disk use during saving that file earlier, so fast start up is more damaging fir disk if that saved kernel memory image is very large ?

Comment: Thumbs up for this, though @snayob did mention this first. Windows 10 will access the file system but not close, if shutting down in hybrid mode.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you changing disk priorities? 
Leave GPT as first disk and select UEFI as default boot.

Firmware boot manager is capable of booting from MBR (when CSM enabled) and you can select boot device using F12 key (may be another key on your system).

When dual-booting, as general rule, you should **disable fast boot in Windows 10**.
Fast boot settings can be changed in Power options(Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options\System Settings - Change Settings that are currently unavailable - uncheck "Turn on fast startup").

Comment: > Leave GPT as first disk and select UEFI as default boot.<BR />

It will boot as Windows 10 only, because this system is on UEFI.

> disable fast boot in Windows 10

This is dual boot but from two disks, so there are actualy two separate single boots, ans mentined settings and disk sequence in BIOS decide which system is chosen.

Comment: You can choose which device to boot using F12 key (boot device selection key, the other function key leads you to firmware setup).

Comment: > Leave GPT as first disk and select UEFI as default boot.:  
It will boot as Windows 10 only, because this system is on UEFI. Perhaps disk GPT + IDE can be omitted by Windows XP which would go to next drive (MBR), but I don't remember. But this computer probably can't boot with MBR as first abd UEFI. I don't want to check this again, because such very frequebt rebooting is not good for disks. Maybe later.

Comment: > disable fast boot in Windows 10:  
This is dual boot but from two disks, so there are actualy two separate single boots, and the mentioned settings and disk sequence in BIOS decide which system is chosen. But maybe I will try this setting.

Answer (score 0):

Open Disk Management and remove the drive letter so neither operating system can access the others partition.